# How to use pagination from prisma1 to prisma2, using Connection

Tags: prisma

I have been using `usersConnection` to manage paginations with this schema in prisma1:

```
"""A connection to a list of items."""
type UserConnection {
  """Information to aid in pagination."""
  pageInfo: PageInfo!

  """A list of edges."""
  edges: [UserEdge]!
  aggregate: AggregateUser!
}

"""An edge in a connection."""
type UserEdge {
  """The item at the end of the edge."""
  node: User!

  """A cursor for use in pagination."""
  cursor: String!
}

type AggregateUser {
  count: Int!
}
```

Now, it's time to migrate to prisma2. I have to keep this format as different frontend are using this schema, Any recommendations to recreate this pagination with prisma2? Should we parsed an re-create the object `users`? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

the solution is:

```
    const users = await ctx.prisma.user.findMany({
      where: args.where,
      skip: args.skip,
      take: args.first,

    })
    return {
      edges: users.map((singleData: Source) => { return { node: singleData } }),
      aggregate: {
        count: await ctx.prisma.user.count({ where: args.where })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent **@prisma/client** has aggregations API with a `count` method (see https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/aggregations)

Here is a nexus example :

```
t.field('usersCount', {
  type: 'Int',
  args: {
    where: 'UserWhereInput',
  },
  resolve: (parent, { where }, { prisma }) => {
    return prisma.user.count({ where }) // <--- the solution
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let {page =undefined,limit=undefined}  = req.body;  
    const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
                     where : {
                       //some conditions
                          role : 1
                         }

                ...( limit !== undefined && 
              page !== undefined
            ? {
             
                skip: limit * page,
                take: limit,
            }
            : {}),

           include : {
               // by assuming user has posts
              Posts : true 
               }
          });
```